# Window is not firing keytyped event

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am making an application without frame. Just like gadgets in Windows.
But I am unable to get key events from this window.
here is my code :

```
JWindow win = new JWindow("gadget");
win.setFocusable(true); 
win.setFocusableWindowState(true);
win.add(mypanel);                     // mypanel is a JPanel that I have created.
win.setSize(300, 100);
win.setLocation(400, 200);
win.addMouseListener(mymouselistener) // mymouselistener is a MouseAdapter
win.addKeyListener(mykeylistener)     // mykeylistener is a KeyAdapter
win.setVisible(true);
```

I am getting mouse events through mymouselistener and it is working fine.
But mykeylistener is not working.

Here is the simple codes for Listeners :

```
MouseAdapter mymouselistener = new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         win.setFocusableWindowState(true);
         System.out.println(e);
     }
 }


KeyAdapter mykeylistener = {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         win.setFocusableWindowState(true);
         System.out.println(e);
     }
 }
```

Comment: For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over the lower level, AWT based, `KeyListener`.

Comment: Can we see the listener code?

Comment: I have added the listener code. @BitNinja

Comment: setWindowFocusableState does do what you think it does

Comment: What does `myPanel` contain?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Did you mean win.setFocusableWindowState(true). It is also not working. myPanel is containing a button so that I can close the window.

Comment: How to make my window to receive keys by key bindings then @AndrewThompson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all `KeyListener` is focus contextual, that means it will only trigger events when the component it is registered to is focusable AND has focus.

The addition of any focusable component in the component hierarchy will immediately effect the listener.

The likely issue is, the `JButton` current has keyboard focus therefore the frame will never receive keyboard events (until, it itself can obtain keyboard focus).

You really shouldn't be using a `KeyListener` against a `JFrame`, a `JFrame` is made up of `JRootPane`, which contains `contentPane` (amongst other things), which, in your context, now contains a `JPanel` with a `JButton`, that's a lot that can get in the way...

Instead you should be using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which allows you to better control the focus level the component needs in order to trigger key events.

You really should, however, use this against your `mypanel`...as it tends to be more contextual.

Also `setFocusableWindowState` will determine if the window is capable of receiving focus at all (including all the child components), best to leave it alone

Comment: I think JButton does not have focus because it should work if I press Enter of Spacebar, but it is not.

Comment: There are simply so many things that could be preventing this from working...if any one of the components in the container hierarchy are focusable, they could prevent the frame from reviving key events.  If the frame itself is not focusable (from the point of view of the key board focus manager), it won't receive events. There are just to many things that will make this go wrong and you simply better off not using it.

Comment: I have editted the code, a look at it. Could you help me get how to make my window focusable. No element in window is getting focus. I know this because focus is still outside of that window, as when I typed a key even after clicking on my window the output is on my last focused window i.e. Netbeans window.

Comment: I need to do some tests, but it'll have to wait till after tea and my daughter goes to bed as my wife is about to kill me for not watching her (my daughter) while she makes tea :P

Comment: Why didn't anybody told me that first. It is working know.@MadProgrammer